# JavaFX: Handle changes in TableColumn

Tags: java, javafx, lambda

I have read [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm) about how to make `TableColumn` editable, I have made some modifications to obtain some reusable code as follows:

```
public static <T> void setEditableColumn(TableColumn<T, String> column, BiConsumer<T,String> modifiedField, String type){

    column.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    column.setOnEditCommit(event->{
        T model = event.getRowValue();
        if(!event.getNewValue().isEmpty()){
            modifiedField.accept(model,event.getNewValue());
        }
    });
}
```

But I want for this method to return the modified Model.

Iit is clear that I retrieve the modified model inside a lambda expression what are the possible ways of doing this. My objective is to be able to save that model in a database.

Comment: The edit commit takes place later.  There is no way your setEditableColumn method can return data for something that hasn’t happened yet.

Comment: any work around this problem?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/247540).  Why do you need a row value when altering a column?  A column has many rows;  which row’s value are you expecting your method to return?

Comment: "My objective is to be able to save that model in a database". You would pass in a consumer that does that: it receives the model and the new value. So just pass a consumer that saves the new data to the database and updates the model with the new value. It's not clear what else you need.